# Vanishing sums of powers modulo n

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Is it possible to describe all positive integer sequences $\{x_i\}$ such that
$$
\sum_i x_i=n
\quad 
\hbox{and}
\quad
\sum_i x_i^k\equiv 0\pmod n
\quad 
\hbox{for all $k$ (and a given $n$)?}
$$

### Background

We say that two elements of a group belong to the same *tribe* if their squares are equal. 
Then

*the sum of $k$*th *powers of tribe sizes is divisible by the order of the group for any positive integer $k$* [http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2824, Example 1].

This remains true if we replace squares (in the definition of tribes) with cubes or any other powers.

Comment: If $n$ is prime, then little Fermat implies the only possibility is for each $x_i$ to be 1. If $d$ is any proper divisor of $n$, then there is a solution in which $x_i=d$ for all $i$. 

Comment: @Gerry, if n is prime, then there are two solutions: n ones and one n. Thanks!